# Find out where application is hanging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, stack

Is there a way to figure out where an application is hanging and not completing its function? I opened the call stack but it is empty. What does this mean. Does anyone have any advice for debugging where an application was the moment it started to hang/become non responsive.

Edit: I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Describe the steps in detail - you start the application with the debugger, I assume? Does your application "hang" immediately, or can you set a breakpoint somewhere at the beginning of your program, which is reached or not reached by the debugger? Is it a GUI or console program or a web application? And so on.

Comment: Sometimes you can even use Baby's First Debugging: print a message before and after all function invocations (or all the relevant ones at least) and see where the program fails to return. Then pick *that* function and add messages at important parts of the code. That way you can hopefully narrow it down. Stepping through the program in a debugger is a more methodical approach, but sometimes the naive method can cut down a lot of search time.

Comment: Well, you read my comment several hours ago but do not showing the slightest effort to increase the quality of your question - so I vote to close it. Don't waste other peoples time by make them guessing around what you could have meant.

Answer (score 2):

Compile your application with **all warnings enabled** and with the **compiler producing debugging information**. On Linux, that means `g++ -Wall -g`. Work on the source code till you got no more warnings.  Learn to use a **debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux), and use its step by step abilities.

But we can't help you more, because this is system dependent and you did not tell what system you are using and you did not show us the code you are debugging.

Read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the post. Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Okay. Serious question here. This is related to my entire program (5k lines) not just a calling function. I have been yelled at before for not including calling code but I am not sure how if I can't really pinpoint where the function is hanging, hence this question.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me, I find attaching the [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) profiler to the debugee often makes it easy to identify where the hang occurred, even if you attach it after it happened - just look for stackframes that were active for 100% of the profiler sampling session (by sorting the list by the "Inclusive %" column and looking at the top).

Comment: Thank you. At the top as 100% it says thread 1188 under thread. Under location, it says "operator new" but occasionally switches to "WinSqmSetIfMaxDWORD". Any ideas as to what this could mean?

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the (at)Omer

Comment: Sorry, no idea, but that method is part of the Windows Kernel. Try to cruise up the stack frame window on the right to try and see what part of *your* code is executing it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the debugger, run a profiler through the code. My VS is rather rusty, so I can't give details on how to do so, but google can help.

It would also help to have many small functions instead of few large ones, as the tightest granularity of the profile is function level.

Answer (score 0):

Put log statements into the code. It is time consuming but some sort of divide and conquer approach should help you solve the problem.